# Displaying a UIViewController within another UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, subview

I am developing an app in which a `UIViewController` (***firstViewController***) contains some `UILabels`, a `UIButton`, and a `UIView` (***subView***). The `UIView` should display the `UIViewController` (***secondViewController***) that contains some layers. I am unable to do this.

What should I do to display ***secondViewController*** within ***subView*** of  ***firstViewController***?

Comment: Add the second view controller as childViewController to first viewController and add second view controller's view as subview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by adding view of another view controller as sub view in view as bellow

```
SecondVC *aObjSecondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];
[self.view addSubview:aObjSecondVC.view]
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use UIViewController containment or parent/child view controllers. You can read details [here](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/containment-view-controller.html).

The most basic version is:

```
UIViewController *parentVC = ...
UIViewController *otherVC = ... // it's view will be added as subview

[parentVC addChildViewController:otherVC];
[parentVC.containerView addSubview:otherVC.view]; // containerView is a view where your child view controller should go
[otherVC didMoveToParentViewController:parentVC];
```

If you only add other view controller's view as a subview, child view controller won't receive all the events. For example, if you use other methods suggested here (just add view as subview and nothing more), you won't get `-viewDidAppear:` message (and others) sent to your child view controller.

Answer (score 4):

You can add it using the following line:

```
[self.subView addSubView:secondViewController.view];
```

Comment: Be aware, that if you do this you will not get the `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` events. A `UIViewController` is **not** designed to be added like this. I would strongly advise against this method. Take a look at MANIAK_dobrii's answer, which handles this the correct way in my opinion.